# Mb_encode_mimeheader in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to use mb_encode_mimeheader but I'm getting an error that it's an undefined function.  Yet I believe it is part of native PHP.

Here is my code:

```
$encoded_subject = mb_encode_mimeheader('my foreign character string', 'UTF-8', 'B');
```

Is this function part of PHP that I need to extend or something?  I've used this function before and never had any problems.

Comment: Did you at least try to read the PHP manual? It clearly states that "mbstring is a non-default extension. This means it is not enabled by default. You must explicitly enable the module with the configure option. See the Install section for details."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the mb_* functions, you need to ensure that the mbstring extension is available/compiled in. (It's not a default extension in terms of the "standard" install, but it is commonly available as a part of most well configured ISP offerings.)

See the Multibyte String [installing/configuring section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.setup.php) within the PHP manual for more information.

Comment: The link tells me how to install PHP?  The PHP is already installed, so how do I configure it at this point.  Where do I enter those strings that it shows for enabling mb_*?

Comment: @shummel7845 The link tells you how to install PHP with the mbstring extension. If you're using an ISP, or an out of the box solution chances are you simply need to enable that extension/module.

Comment: Our cPanel uses a dashboard approach to edit the php.ini.  I found an option called mb_encoding_translation and turned it on but that didn't do it.  Everything else looks enabled.  Suggestions?  I've contacted my ISP and am awaiting a return email.

Comment: @shummel7845 Can you edit which PHP extensions/modules are enabled? (i.e.: Not just the PEAR modules?) If not, you'll need to get your ISP to add/enable this for you - hopefully this will be a fairly painless process.

Comment: No unfortunately I have limited control over this.  Hopefully the ISP can take care of this.  Thanks for all your help, middaparka.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/mbstring.installation

As mentioned there its not enabled by default. there is also mentioned, how to enable it.